# How can I make Selenium use my firefox (not create a fresh one)

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I am new to selenium.
I found selenium would not use my local firefox browser. Seems it create a fresh one with no plugin.
But I want do something with plugin on, such as: `modify request headers`, `aotuproxy`. I only found setting headers example in java. 
 Though proxy can be set by using `webdriver.FirefoxProfile().set_preference('network.proxy.http',....`,  it is not so sweet to fit my aim.
So I think it would be very nice to make selenium use my firefox. But I can not figure it out.

Comment: Do you want it to use a browser instance you already have open and running, or do you want it to use your profile, plugins, settings, etc.?

Comment: @user2357112 I want it start a browser instance to use my custom FireFox profile, plugins, settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I find the answer.Give a profile path is the point.

```
def get_ffprofile():
    ff_profile_path = 'C:\\Users\\Kasim\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\my89fce2.default'
    ff_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(ff_profile_path)
    return ff_profile
```

then

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=get_ffprofile())
```

Will start my browser(actually a browser instance with my custom profile in another word)

Answer (score 1):

Selenium cannot connect to an existing browser. It can only launch new instances.